# What is the main difference betwen pybuilder and pygradle

Tags: python, build, pybuilder, pygradle

I am recently learning python and figuring out a build tool to use. I stumbled upon pybuilder and pygradle. Could not find a difference between these tools in internet. Would like to know when to choose what , their individual strengths and limitations.

Thanks